# Vim Windows Autocommand Filename = 8.3

Tags: vim

I try to identify a file by its name.

E.g. I have the following files:

- 2300039_2234552_779799_ABC.xml
- 2234439_2456644_123423_XYZ.xml

and the following autocommand:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.xml call CheckFileType()
```

For a test case I just save the current filename to a global variable.

```
function! CheckFileType()
   let g:filename = expand("%:p:t")
endfunction
```

When the file has finished loading, I echo the filename:

```
echo g:filename
```

The result: 223443~1.XML

But for identification I need the complete filename!

When I reload the file afterward and echo the filename again, I get the long filename.
wtf???

This behavior only appears, when loading the file from extern (e.g. "C:\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe" --remote-silent C:\2234439_2456644_123423_XYZ.xml). When loading from intern (:e) everything is as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get the same behavior with `let g:filename = expand("<afile>")` on `CheckFileType` function?

Comment: Depending on your application you could also try `BufWinEnter`.

Comment: Nice that you solved it! Maybe it is a good idea post the solution as an answer to make it easier to read if someone else face a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason; this little snippet in my XML-Filetype-Plugin causes my problems:

```
if (getfsize(expand("%:8")) < 5000000)
   set foldmethod=syntax
else
   set foldmethod=manual
endif
```

It seems, that Vim remembers this expand-call...